# Comparing python performance from hardware specifics

Tags: python, performance, processor

I am running some simulations in Python on my laptop, for my master degree project, and recently discovered that my desktop computer has almost the same performance of my laptop, when performing the same exact code. The problem is that my laptop has an i7 processor, while the desktop computer an i3. More specifically:

Laptop:  i7-5500U @2.40 GHz (64bit, dual core)

Desktop: i3-4150  @3.50 GHz (32bit, one core)

I am not an expert on computer science, neither I study it, and this is quite surprising to me. I know that the number of cores should not affect the performance, since python only uses one, but does it really all rely on clock frequency? And if yes, what are the advantages of having an i7 with such clock frequency? Is there some other data I am missing? What data one has to take under consideration to forecast computer's performance?

Comment: Definitely, the clock rate matters. But so will, for example, the system architecture (64 bit vs 32 bit), and many other things, depending on what you are doing. Note, Python programs *can definitely take advantage of multiple cores*, so again, it **really** depends. There isn't enough information here to say anything useful.

Comment: The program under examination just uses numpy to perform random sampling and multidimensional array manipulation. Usually I set the data type of numbers equal to "int8", to save memory, since the arrays are very large. No multithreading or things like that. How does the architecture affect the performance?

Comment: Um, numpy *heavily* relies on multithreaded code, depending on the exact BLAS/LAPACK backend. It is a typical example of when Python code will take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: If it uses multithreaded, shouldn't the dual core processor perform better? Or this means that, if it hadn't two cores, the comparison between the i3 and i7 would be even more embarrassing?

Comment: Hard to say without more information. Note, if you are using uint8, this is smaller than either architecture's word-size, which will generally slow you down when doing things like arithmetic on primitive numeric types, but it's hard to predict entirely, since things like the size of your array and the cache size will play a large role as well. How much memory are you working with? Have you tried using the native size?

Comment: Another thing, is your desktop CPU actually a 32bit processor? Or are you just running a 32bit python process on a 64 bit machine? Because if your CPU is 64bit you should definitely try running it on a 64bit python... 32bit is legacy and has been for a while.

Comment: The script produces the temporal evolution of a system, which requires producing something like 10^11 random bernoulli (i.e. 0 or 1) extractions per timestep. If numbers where bigger than int8 it would require too much ram. I do this using np.random.bytes and some necessary manipulations with array's pointwise multiplication and sum. The desktop is a 32bit machine!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not, I'm pretty sure it's x86-64, but you have a 32bit Windows installation or something.

Comment: If this is the case, changing the windows version would improve simulation times?

Comment: Maybe, all of this is speculation

Answer (score 0):

There are really too many factors in determining why your performance is like that. Consider:

- Is your program memory-bound or calculation-bound?
- Does your code really use multiple cores?
- Is your program slowed down by disk access?
- Are you using different language versions or performance settings?

There are really many factors like these; some of them are difficult to answer and impossible to guess.

You could try profiling this if important enough.

Comment: I am not sure I understood everything you said. My script produces the temporal evolution of a system, which requires producing something like 10^11 random bernoulli (i.e. 0 or 1) extractions per timestep. If numbers where bigger than int8 it would require too much ram. I do this using np.random.bytes and some necessary manipulations with array's pointwise multiplication and sum.